# Suppress Warning "Field May Be Final" for Serializable

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gwt, final, code-inspection

In IntelliJ I activated the "Field May Be Final" inspection because of the project's coding guidelines.

But this makes no sense for `Serializable` classes, where `final` fields would cause serialization problems. Is there a possibility to automatically suppress this warning for classes that implement the `Serializable`  interface? My current workaround is to use `@SuppressWarnings("FieldMayBeFinal")`.

As a reaction to Kayaman's comment: Serialization of final fields is an issue here as this does not work with the `GWT` framework. Sorry, I should have mentioned that.

[image]

Comment: No problem with serialization.

Comment: Thank you for your hint but serialization of final fields is an issue here as this does not work with the GWT framework. Sorry, I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Yes you should have. I can "dupehammer" this singlehandedly, but apparently I can't reopen this without 4 other votes. What the hell.

Comment: @Kayaman That's because OP removed the java tag where you have the dupehammer.

Comment: @approxiblue Ah, I thought it behaved differently than I remembered.

Comment: Re-added it... what an adventure ;-)